# Apple ios API - Telephony

Tags: ios

Can I listen to incoming call from my application and originate new calls? May I know the listener for call receiver?
At high level, I see there are no API's to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I listen to incoming call from my application

Yes you can detect incoming call using [Core Telephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) if your app is running on foreground. For background detection you may use [`CTCallCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604). `CTCallCenter` can tell you about any in-progress or started calls.

However, you can't information about the caller

> originate new calls?

You can not modify, reject, accept incoming call from your application, however to generate new call, you can use following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telPrompt:%@", cellNumberString]]];
```

This will open call screen of your device with number already entered but will not originate calls.

Apple doesn't allow apps to originate/modify/accept/reject calls. Users do that by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't.

iOS does not allow to "replace" the functionality of Phone app. However, you can trigger Phone app to make phone calls by `tel://` or `telprompt://` custom URL scheme.